# Problem with PhpStorm Red Line Under <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: ide, phpstorm

So the problem I'm having is that when I either create a new php project or open one of my old projects, I instantly get a small red line under just the `<` on the html `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.

The reason this is a problem is because I cannot open my previews in the IDE to see what my index.html file looks like on the browser.

Here is the picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: PhpStorm Red Line]

Comment: Not super sure what you did ... but it's not HTML. I mean -- the file is not treated as HTML in IDE eyes. Yes, it has HTML syntax highlighting, but it's incomplete + that error that you are talking about. Based on your screenshot IDE treats the file as plain text ... and then some plugin on top processes it as HTML. Most likely it's Textmate bundles plugin. It means that your IDE config is somehow partially broken/misconfigured due to some reason.

Comment: Please go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, locate an entry for `HTML` file type and show what patterns you have registered there. Do the same for `Text` file type. It must be an issue with one (or more) of the patterns there...

Comment: Im not sure what I did either because this is how I've made a html file in the past and it worked fine

Comment: If you show those screenshots that I've asked, I may see what potentially can be wrong there (I believe one of those places where the misconfiguration is).

Comment: In the text file types index.html was one of the patterns so I deleted that and it worked. Thank you for your help! @LazyOne

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if the textmate bundles are used for file highlighting.
Please open the **Settings | Editor | File Types** page and make sure that `*.html` pattern is assigned to **HTML** file type there:

[image]

Comment: It is, when I make a .html file named something other than index it works now. But index.html does not work.

Comment: it means that `index.html` pattern is assigned to some other file type, *Text*, for example